# Configure and use AutoMapper in ASP.Net Framwork API

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper in Asp.Net Framework API (not core) and when I try to use, my model DTO gets all attributes null.

I tried a lot of solutions and a lots are deprecated. So, my actual solution is:

1. Create a Configuration class

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static IMapper _mapper { get; set; }

    public static void Register()
    {
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(
            config => 
            {
                config.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
            }
        );

        _mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    }

}
```

2. Load at the start in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMapping();
}
```

3. Take model from .edmx and create a DTO

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    //I need only this 3
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

4. Create a Profile

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

5. Use AutoMapper in a Controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    readonly IMapper mapper = AutoMapperConfig._mapper;

    public List<UserDto> Get()
    {
        using(var ctx = new DbEntities())
        {
            var src = ctx.User.ToList;
            var dst = new List<UserDto>();
            src.ForEach(u = > dst.Add(mapper.Map<UserDto>(u)));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for some kind of reason, I get all object in dst List null. For example, I have 3 object in DB and when I call this method I retrive 3 DTO objects but with all params null. Why?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Comment: I saw only for Core projects. Could you help me to implements this in my Asp.Net Web Application? (I'm pretty new in .Net)

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: Hi @DavidLiang. Unfortunately I don't know what version I had used, because I had deleted this project to restart in .Net Core 6 with EF Core Power Tools. This solution is more stable and more quickly for developing.